# PHP mb_substr dividing error utf 8

Tags: php, string, unicode, substring, multibyte

I'm trying to divide a string into two columns with 6 lines in each. The problem is that if the last line contains (Ø,Æ,Å) it will jump into the next column even though there is a space in the first.

It seems like this is a problem with encoding, anyone got a clue what might be going on? The code I am using to generate the columns is:

```
$iter = 6;
$str = $shortd;
$count_line = 0;
$str = $shortd;
for ($x=0; $x<$iter;){
  $pos = strpos($str,"<br />");
  $text = mb_substr ($str, 0, $pos + 6);
  $str = mb_substr ($str, $pos + 6);
  echo $text;
  $x++;
}
?>
</td>
<td>
<?
for ($x=$iter; $x<$iter + $iter;){
  $pos = strpos($str,"<br />");
  $text = mb_substr ($str, 0, $pos + 6);
  $str = mb_substr ($str, $pos + 6);
  echo $text;
  $x++;
}
?>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you noticed the last (optional) argument `string $encoding` of [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) function is not multi-byte aware. You should use [mb_strpos()](https://www.php.net/mb_strpos) instead. Otherwise, you are mixing bytes and characters when dealing with positions.

Comment: Thanks alot, this did however not solve the problem. The output seems to be alot of space when having the specific chars resulating in the text being split and showed into the second column.